# Optimization suggestions for Laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm creating a Laravel 5.1 application that lists products on pages. Now each product on the database has the url of the product detail page. I have done a method that exports all those urls and convert's them to laravel routes, and the routes are written into a file and included on the laravel routing. I have done that on that way in order to be able to optimize the routing using laravel's **routes:cache** command. Now my question in fact is about optimization, which way would be better, to have a file with all routes, let's say 100K routes or to have a single entrance point that compares the route in question inside the database and return the respective product.

Comment: Latter. Don't create a gazillion routes. Simplify your routes, have them include a parameter which you then use for a database lookup. Absolutely.

Comment: @Here2Help, I'm not so sure I agree with this entirely, adding a DB lookup to a request just adds to the request time and may be detrimental to performance even.Maybe a bunch of caching will help the situation a little but I think it's a bad idea.

Comment: @vsharper Having a DB lookup is precisely what product-driven websites _should_ do. What, you think he should update his routes file every time a new product is added? Might as well just build a static website then, forget Laravel and PHP.

Comment: @Here2Help, quite the opposite, I think the answer below suffices quite well as to what I was looking to say. So the route would inevitably pass the param onto the controller which would handle the request, not the route. I thought the question was alluding to 100k routes being stored in the DB, which is equally diabolical.

Comment: @vsharper I have to disagree with your comment. On the site the only entrance point for products is a CSV file import. Every time a file is imported then the virtual routing component adds the routes to the site.

Comment: @vsharper the answer below has a parameter defined in the _route_ first. =) then it gets passed to a controller, where a DB lookup is performed. Which is exactly what I proposed in my first comment. glad we agree at least!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a need to have an individual route for each product. Possibly Store a unique slug(Semantic URL) in the database? Then have one route that displays a product based on a what is passed to the route.

user friendly slug could be something like 't-shirt-9000'. If you don't want this, you can always use the unique id you already have set for the product in the database.

Within your show method, you would need to query the DB with the slug past in the request to the database.

quick example:

In routes.php

```
Route::get('/products/{product}', 'ProductController@show');
```

Product Controller

```
public function show($product)
{
    $productRequested = Product::where('url_slug', $product)->first();
    // Do whatever from here
}
```

Comment: Yes! This. Except, you call the parameter `product` in your route, but `$productRequested` in the controller. Might want to fix that.

Comment: Yea, i forgot it needs to be named the same. fixed!

Comment: It doesn't need to be named the same but it's probably good to be less confusing.

Comment: @AndrewNolan I agree with you, and I know that your approach is the best valid approach, but the client requirements specify that the url that leads to the product details page is specified in the CSV file that is used to import the products on the system. No slug no hash for the url, just the client specified one.

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you use a framework you will be enforced to optimize your code

route file allow you to get the fastest way to minimize the number of mapped URLs.

the notion of route offered by Symfony to laravel allow you to manipulate all variables of your url with one single route , for example :

```
route::get('{category}/{id}/{slug}/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}/{varX}','yourController@yourMethod');
```

this route will send all variables in the url to `yourMethod();`